# what does "no less" mean in "The correct combination – with important – is no less effective."?

Tags: grammar, interpretation

I've been looking up the meaning of "no less" for a while but still don't get its meaning fully.

here is a full context.

> The next pair above (important/essential) have different strengths of meaning. Essential means very important. Because it already possesses the idea of “very”, it cannot normally be used after strength-showing adverbs like slightly, quite or very – it is a “non-gradable” adjective. Very in particular is commonly combined incorrectly with essential by learners of English. The correct combination – with important – is no less effective.

could it mean "The correct combination – with important – cannot be ineffective while strength-showing adverbs + essential is."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No less** means **not any less than**.

So, if I say that bottle A holds **no less** than bottle B, it means that bottle A does not hold less (liquid etc) than bottle B. It may hold as much or it may hold more.

If house A is no less attractive than house B, it is at least as attractive as house B.

So the paragraph concerns adjectives that cannot be graded, like **dead, unique** or **essential**. Either creatures are dead or they aren't; objects are unique or they aren't and things are essential or they aren't.

But **important is different. Some things are much more important than others. **Important** is a gradable adjective.

The bottom line means that it is no less effective (just as effective) to describe something as very important as it is to describe it as essential.